# Extract array of JSONs to columns in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table with JSON collections:

| ID | SliderJson |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"Slider":11, "Value":2},{"Slider":4, "Value":3}] |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | [{"Slider":11, "Value":4},{"Slider":4, "Value":3},{"Slider":25, "Value":3},{"Slider":2, "Value":4},{"Slider":5, "Value":3}] |

As can be see in the example not all records have a value, and those that have the length of the array vary (by a maximum of 9 items).
Ideally I would like to create a column for each slider that contains its entry value, but there are about 400 million records and about 80 different sliders.

So I would be happy to create a columns only for certain sliders, say 4 and 5 and get the following table.

| ID | SliderJson | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"Slider":11, "Value":2},{"Slider":4, "Value":3}] | 3 | NULL |
| 2 |  | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | [{"Slider":11, "Value":4},{"Slider":4, "Value":3},{"Slider":25, "Value":3},{"Slider":2, "Value":4},{"Slider":5, "Value":3}] | 3 | 3 |

Or alternatively create a table that will extract the json to the columns in the following way:

| ID | SliderJson | slider1 | value1 | slider2 | value2 | slider3 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"Slider":11, "Value":2},{"Slider":4, "Value":3}] | 11 | 2 | 4 | 3 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 |  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | [{"Slider":11, "Value":4},{"Slider":4, "Value":3},{"Slider":25, "Value":3},{"Slider":2, "Value":4},{"Slider":5, "Value":3}] | 11 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 25 | 3 |

Both options are good and working for me, the only consideration is efficiency because as mentioned there are a millions of records (and maybe there are other options that are preferred and I have not thought about).
It also important that each record be associated with its original id.

So far I tried the following proceeder, however even when I execute it on very small amount of rows (only 100) it took hours, so I guess something wrong.

```
DECLARE @NOTE_ID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @USER_ID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @SINGEL_SLIDER NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE SLIDER_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT [NoteID],[UserID],[SliderJSON]  FROM [dbo].[SmallData]
OPEN SLIDER_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM SLIDER_CURSOR INTO @NOTE_ID, @USER_ID, @SINGEL_SLIDER
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

IF len(@SINGEL_SLIDER)>1
    BEGIN 

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TMP') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TMP 

        SELECT *
        INTO #TMP
        FROM OPENJSON(@SINGEL_SLIDER)

        DECLARE @SLIDER_VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX)

        DECLARE SLIDER_VALUE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT [value]  FROM #TMP
        OPEN SLIDER_VALUE_CURSOR
        FETCH NEXT FROM SLIDER_VALUE_CURSOR INTO  @SLIDER_VALUE
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TMP1') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TMP1

        SELECT *
        INTO #TMP1
        FROM OPENJSON(@SLIDER_VALUE)

        DECLARE @SLIDER_ID NVARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @SLIDER_OPTION_ID  NVARCHAR(100)

        SET @SLIDER_ID = (SELECT [value] FROM #TMP1 WHERE [key] = 'Slider')
        SET @SLIDER_OPTION_ID = (SELECT [value] FROM #TMP1 WHERE [key] = 'Value')

        IF @SLIDER_ID = 4 
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [dbo].[SmallData]
                SET [4] = @SLIDER_OPTION_ID
                WHERE [NoteID] = @NOTE_ID
            END
        ELSE IF @SLIDER_ID = 7 
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [dbo].[SmallData]
                SET [7] = @SLIDER_OPTION_ID
                WHERE [NoteID] = @NOTE_ID
            END
        ELSE IF @SLIDER_ID = 1
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [dbo].[SmallData]
                SET [1] = @SLIDER_OPTION_ID
                WHERE [NoteID] = @NOTE_ID
            END
        ELSE IF @SLIDER_ID = 10
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [dbo].[SmallData]
                SET [10] = @SLIDER_OPTION_ID
                WHERE [NoteID] = @NOTE_ID
            END
        ELSE IF @SLIDER_ID = 43
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [dbo].[SmallData]
                SET [43] = @SLIDER_OPTION_ID
                WHERE [NoteID] = @NOTE_ID
            END
        ELSE IF @SLIDER_ID = 15
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [dbo].[SmallData]
                SET [15] = @SLIDER_OPTION_ID
                WHERE [NoteID] = @NOTE_ID
            END
        ELSE IF @SLIDER_ID = 18
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [dbo].[SmallData]
                SET [18] = @SLIDER_OPTION_ID
                WHERE [NoteID] = @NOTE_ID
            END
    END

 FETCH NEXT FROM SLIDER_VALUE_CURSOR INTO @SLIDER_VALUE
END 

CLOSE SLIDER_VALUE_CURSOR  
DEALLOCATE SLIDER_VALUE_CURSOR 

FETCH NEXT FROM SLIDER_CURSOR INTO @NOTE_ID, @USER_ID, @SINGEL_SLIDER 
END 

CLOSE SLIDER_CURSOR  
DEALLOCATE SLIDER_CURSOR
```

I would appreciate any help on this subject.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Have you looked into using `OPENJSON`? what about the functionalitu didn't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why you thought you needed all those cursors and a temp table, they are unnecessary.

**You need two `OPENJSON`s here. To get just the value for each slider, you can just pivot on the slider number.**

```sql
SELECT
  s.*,
  j.*
FROM dbo.SmallData s
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      pvt.*
    FROM (
        SELECT
          j2.Slider,
          j2.Value
        FROM OPENJSON (s.SliderJSON) j1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j1.value)
          WITH (Slider int, Value int) j2
    ) j
    PIVOT (
        MIN(Value) FOR Slider IN
        ([4],[5])
    ) pvt
) j;
```

**Your second version can also be done pretty simply with a multi-column pivot**.

```sql
SELECT
  s.*,
  j.*
FROM dbo.SmallData s
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '0' THEN j2.Slider END) slider1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '0' THEN j2.Value  END)  value1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '1' THEN j2.Slider END) slider2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '1' THEN j2.Value  END)  value2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '2' THEN j2.Slider END) slider3,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '2' THEN j2.Value  END)  value3,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '3' THEN j2.Slider END) slider4,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '3' THEN j2.Value  END)  value4,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '4' THEN j2.Slider END) slider5,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '4' THEN j2.Value  END)  value5,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '5' THEN j2.Slider END) slider6,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '5' THEN j2.Value  END)  value6,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '6' THEN j2.Slider END) slider7,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '6' THEN j2.Value  END)  value7,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '7' THEN j2.Slider END) slider8,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '7' THEN j2.Value  END)  value8,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '8' THEN j2.Slider END) slider9,
      MAX(CASE WHEN j1.[key] = '8' THEN j2.Value  END)  value9
    FROM OPENJSON (s.SliderJSON) j1
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j1.value)
      WITH (Slider int, Value int) j2
) j;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! the query option work great, however for the first query I get 'Ambiguous column name 'Value'.' Any suggestion?